# Jplayer playback with delay

Tags: jquery, html, jplayer

Here is my code of jplayer. The problem is that it works fine in **Chrome, Opera, Firefox**, but when browsed in the **Safari browser** on  desktop there is some delay in playback. I don't know why is this happened. Any help or suggestion please.

HTML:

```
<div id="#jpId1"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#jpId1").jPlayer({
     ready: function () { // The $.jPlayer.event.ready event
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { // Set the media
            wav: "sound/sound1.wav",
        }).jPlayer("stop"); // Attempt to auto play the media
    },
        ended: function () { // The $.jPlayer.event.ended event
            $(this).jPlayer("play"); // Repeat the media
        },
        supplied: "wav"
    }
);
```

Comment: add loop: true after supplied: "wav",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delay will remain same if you choose jPlayer. An option as replacement is Web Api. You can use Web Api to escape from delays.
Here Is the link:
[Web Api](http://forestmist.org/blog/web-audio-api-loops)